# How to load one image and use it twice using HTML&CSS? No JS

Tags: html, css, image, load

I'm designing my future blog page, and i realized that most of people load the same exact image twice, in this case a bigger logo image and a medium or small logo image.

The thing is, you already loaded a big logo image, so why waste resources loading a smaller version instead of just using the same image and resizing it with css?

I couldn't find any reason to do that, so i began to think of methods to use the same image several times, reducing the http request and page load time.

The idea i have now is using a sprite with just 1 image, the big logo, then you just use it twice:

- Full logo: just use it as you would use any other sprite image
- Medium logo: Resized sprite image

Right now this is the best way i found to do it:
http://tobyj.net/responsive-sprites/#notes

I am looking for the best way to do this, or another alternative, but no JS, having to load a js file defeats the purpose of reducing HTTP requests.

What do you think? any ideas?
Greetings.

SOLVED: Thanks guys, it was easier than i thought, and now i'm thinking, who the hell design the templates? they add a ton of duplicated not needed HTTP requests and code :S

Comment: Im so confused by this... You just said resize using CSS.. Thats it.... Resize the larger image to a smaller size. Unless I missed something in the question.

Comment: What about SVG image?

Comment: [**This**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/1xtmrrn8/) loads one time and is two different sizes....

Comment: @NachoVeiga So use background position to select what parts you want.

Comment: @NachoVeiga [Demo of that](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/1xtmrrn8/1/). And why post the question then? JS will always be better for older browsers. Also IE 9 can handle background-position. So its not too bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

**1. Resize the img**

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.big-logo {
  width: 100%;
}
.medium-logo {
  width: 50%;
}
.small-logo {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-logo">
  <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png" />
</div>

<div class="medium-logo">
  <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png" />
</div>

<div class="small-logo">
  <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png" />
</div>
```

**2. Use the image as a background**

```css
.big-logo, 
.medium-logo, 
.small-logo {
  background: url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png') no-repeat top left;
  background-size: cover;
  
}
.big-logo{
  width: 500px;
  height: 149px;
}
.medium-logo {
  width: 250px;
  height: 74px;
}
.small-logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 44px;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-logo"></div>

<div class="medium-logo"></div>

<div class="small-logo"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry Ruddy, i'm pretty new on web design ^^